# How to get around date parameter in SQL Server stored procedure to get back all data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, get

I am currently using a `getShifts` stored procedure to get data for 2 separate features on the front end. My stored procedure requires a parameter `Selected Date` which when passed a date returns records for the specific date.

I am trying to bypass the `ShiftDate` parameter for one of my features and have it act as a get all. Is there a way to pass a fake date to the stored procedure in order to receive all records?

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        n.ID, n.ID, m.SearchFullNameFL as ProfileName, n.SchedID, 
        s.LicenseID, f.ID as UnitID, f.UnitName, 
        n.Hours, s.ShiftDate, s.SchedShiftID, ss.Description as SchedShift,  
        ss.Hours as SchedShiftHours, t.ID as TransactionTypeId,
        (SELECT COUNT(b.ID) 
         FROM Sched b
         INNER JOIN Ref_SchedShift ss ON ss.ID = b.SchedShiftID AND ss.DSN > 0
         WHERE b.ExpiredBy = 0 AND b.ShiftDate = @ShiftDate -->= @StartDate 
           AND b.EndDate <= @EndDate
           AND b.FacUnitID IN (SELECT Id FROM FacUnit 
                               WHERE FacilityID = @FacilityID) 
           AND b.ID = s.ID) AS ShiftsWorked,
        n.OverTimeReasonTypeID, n.Comment, n.Ref_NoLunchID as NoLunchID, 
        nl.NoLunchType
    FROM
        NewClockIns n
    INNER JOIN 
        Members m ON m.ID = n.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Sched s ON s.ID = n.SchedID AND s.ExpiredBy = 0
    INNER JOIN 
        Ref_Method rm ON n.Ref_MethodID = rm.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Ref_ClockTransactionType t ON t.ID = n.Ref_ClockTransID
    INNER JOIN 
        FacUnit f ON f.ID = n.FacUnitID
    INNER JOIN 
        Ref_License l ON l.ID = s.LicenseID
    INNER JOIN 
        Ref_SchedShift ss ON ss.Id = s.SchedShiftID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Ref_NoLunch nl ON nl.ID = n.Ref_NoLunchID
    WHERE  
        s.ShiftDate = @ShiftDate-->= @StartDate 
        AND s.EndDate <= @EndDate 
        AND s.ClockInsAgencyApprovedByID > 0 
        AND ((@IsApproved = 1 AND s.ClockInsFacilityApprovedByID > 0) 
             OR 
             (@IsApproved = 0 AND s.ClockInsFacilityApprovedByID = 0)) 
        AND f.Id IN (SELECT ID FROM @UnitIDList) 
        AND n.ExpiredBy = 0
END
```

Comment: Are you able to update the stored procedure? Because if not, then the answer is most likely "run it for every date you want".

Comment: what are your`Selected Date` parameters in your query?

Comment: This 1 stored proc is currently being used for 2 different features with a flag of isApproved, so when the shift is `Approved` the date picker is needed to filter them out, but when it is not approved then that is when I am would like to display all the data without a date .

Comment: `Selected Date` should have been `ShiftDate` I edited the post with the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `or`?

```
(s.ShiftDate = @ShiftDate or @ShiftDate is null)
```

Then `NULL` can be passed in and the filter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ShiftDate =(Case When @IsApproved = 1 Then @ShiftDate Else null End)
```